# Solaris 8 start in console Mode

Tags: solaris

I have a machine Solaris-8 in my company that the motherboard was replaced yesterday.

When starting the machine today, it automatically goes to console mode and i can't access to the login with the graphic mode.
And i don't know why .

I searched in the internet about that problem and about Solaris-8 but no solutions . I want to access only to the graphic mode . Can you help me please ?

I also try after starting the machine in console mode, the command `cat /.dt/startlog` and i got this :

```
 --- /usr/dt/bin/Xsession starting...
--- starting /usr/openwin/bin/speckeysd
--- Xsession started by dtlogin
--- starting /usr/dt/bin/dtsession_res -load -system
--- sourcing //.dtprofile...
--- sourcing /usr/dt/config/Xsession.d/0010.dtpaths...
--- sourcing /usr/dt/config/Xsession.d/0015.sun.env...
--- sourcing /usr/dt/config/Xsession.d/0020.dtims...
--- sourcing /usr/dt/config/Xsession.d/0030.dttmpdir...
--- sourcing /usr/dt/config/Xsession.d/0040.xmbind...
--- sourcing /usr/dt/config/Xsession.d/1000.solregis...
--- could not read //.profile
--- starting /usr/dt/bin/dthello &
--- starting /usr/dt/bin/dtsearchpath
--- starting /usr/dt/bin/dtappgather &
--- starting /usr/dt/bin/dsdm &
--- session log file is /dev/null
--- DTSOURCEPROFILE is 'true' (see //.dtprofile)
--- execing /usr/dt/bin/dtsession with a /sbin/sh login shell ...
--- starting desktop on /dev/pts/3
/usr/dt/bin/ttsession[705]: starting
X connection to :0.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

Can someone have an idea about this .?
Thank you

Comment: What logs can you find in `/var/dt`?  (I hope I'm remembering that correctly...)  This link might be useful:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7492/loginmanager-34803/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable, then enable desktop

```
/usr/dt/bin/dtconfig -d
/usr/dt/bin/dtconfig -e
```

and then start desktop with command

```
/etc/init.d/dtlogin start
```

P.S. In case of problem please check those log files:

```
/var/dt/Xerrors
/.dt/startlog
/.dt/errorlog
/.dt/sessionlogs
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but nothing happened :/

Comment: @Hohenheim, I update my answer. Please try again

Comment: thanks Romeo, actually i don't have the machine besides me but i can acces toit with `rlogin` command. I execute the commands as `root` and i reboot after that . But i don't think that worked :/ Do i have to tell someone there to put the commands himself ?

Comment: @Hohenheim, if you are not in front of the machine can you please clarify about what kind of graphic interface you talk about? Please update your question

Comment: i'm using Exceed to try to connect to the machine, normally i'll get an interface which i can put the login and the password, but actually when i try to connect i can't, i have nothing in display. I can only access with the command `rlogin`

Comment: Please check my updated answer with the list of logs you can check

Comment: i edited my question Romeo can you read it plz thnx

Answer (score 0):

What model server?  And with a motherboard change, are you trying to boot off the same drive?  And other OBP settings verified?

Are you excluding modules/drivers in /etc/system?  I have a recollection that a usb (ohci?) driver was being excluded on an old Solaris 8 desktop that caused the Xserver to not start.

Since you can login via rlogin or telnet, what does a `ps -aef |grep X` show?